# How can i make my Etch-A-Sketch grid change color and opacity when hovered?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to do an etch a sketch assignment. I was able to produce the grid with the **createGrids function**, but with **changeGridColor function** and **resetButton function** added the grids created by **createGrids function** will disappear. And I have been trying to change the color of the grids to random colors and increase opacity when hovered but it's not working. How will I achieve that, please? Check the code.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="etch-a-sketch.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Etch-A-Sketch</h1>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="resetButton">Reset</div>
        <script src="etch-a-sketch.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;

}

h1{
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: bolder;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(185, 113, 113);
    margin-top: 0px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    width: 960px;
    height: 960px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box{
   border: 1px solid black;
}

.resetButton{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 40px;
    width: 90px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px
}
```

JS

```
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
let resetButton = document.querySelector("resetButton");

function createGrids(gridNumber = 16) {
  let containerSize = Number(960);
  let gridSize = Number(gridNumber);
  for (let rowCol = 0; rowCol < gridSize ** 2; rowCol++){
      let gridCell = document.createElement("div");
      gridCell.style.height = `${(containerSize / gridSize) - 2}px`;
      gridCell.style.width = `${(containerSize / gridSize) - 2}px`;
      gridCell.classList.add("box");
      container.appendChild(gridCell);
  }
}

function changeGridColor(event) {
  let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  let c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${a}, ${b}, ${c})`;
  event.target.style.opacity += 0.1;

  console.log(event)
}

function resetButton() {
  let gridNumber = +prompt("Enter the grid size you want:", 16);
  while (container.firstChild) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }
  createGrids(gridNumber);
}

let resetButton = document.querySelector("resetButton");
resetButton.onclick = resetButton();

let gridCells = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
gridCells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener("mouseover", changeGridColor));

window.onload = function () {createGrids();};
```

Comment: The easiest way is to use the css `:hover` selector: `some-element-class-or-id:hover { /*styles that only apply when pointer over element */ }`

Comment: @JDunken the background color of the grid boxes should be changing to random color when hovered.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are adding the listeners to cells that are not yet added to the DOM.

   - Add the `mouseover` to the cells when creating them.
2. You can also grab the grid size from the container element.

```js
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
let size = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(container).width, 10);

function createGrid(gridSize = 16) {
  for (let rowCol = 0; rowCol < gridSize ** 2; rowCol++) {
    let gridCell = document.createElement("div");
    Object.assign(gridCell.style, {
      height : `${(size / gridSize) - 2}px`,
      width : `${(size / gridSize) - 2}px`
    });
    gridCell.classList.add("box");
    gridCell.addEventListener('mouseover', changeGridColor)
    container.appendChild(gridCell);
  }
}

let resetButton = document.querySelector(".resetButton");
resetButton.addEventListener('click', handleResetButton);

window.onload = function() {
  createGrid();
};

function changeGridColor(e) {
  let color = `rgb(${[0, 0, 0].map(channel => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  }).join(',')})`
  Object.assign(e.target.style, {
    backgroundColor : color,
    opacity : 0.25
  });
}

function handleResetButton(e) {
  let gridNumber = +prompt("Enter the grid size you want:", 16);
  while (container.firstChild) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }
  createGrid(gridNumber);
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(185, 113, 113);
  margin-top: 0px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.resetButton {
  border: 1px solid #222;
  height: 40px;
  width: 90px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #F7F7F7;
}

.resetButton:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1>Etch-A-Sketch</h1>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="resetButton">Reset</div>
```